# compare current system date with date with type datetime stored in database in android

Tags: android, database, date, time

I Create a table with a field for date(type datetime) that default is current date,when user insert data,this time set automatically,i want to compare current system date with this field,what do i do?

```
public static long s;

 String query = "SELECT Cart_Date from Tbl_Cart where Cart_ID="+lastId+" ";

          Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
           if (c != null && c.moveToFirst() ) {
               s = c.getLong(0);
}
 if( System.getTimeInMillis()!=s)
```

{
..
}
it is my code,but it doesn t work

Comment: You need to show more than this.  if( System.getTimeInMillis()!=s) will always be true unless you work very hard to do something very odd.

Comment: which exact part 'doesn't work'?

Comment: line  if( System.getTimeInMillis()!=s),always is true!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, seems the author of the question has meant the following:

> He's storing ms from epoch in the database and need to compare calendar date which corresponds to that value with the current one.

To resolve it, I would suggest to use the following code:

```
    // get current date    
    final Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Calendar dateFromDB = Calendar.getInstance();

    dateFromDB.setTimeInMillis(s);
```

Now you can compare rightNows and DateFromDB year, month and day fields using [Calendar.get(int field)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29).

There's another implementation possible - write Your own function for conversion from ms to days (e.g. using [Julian Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day))

Also, You should have in mind the following: Time in DB and current times might have different timezones so You might need to make additional corrections for that;

Answer (score 0):

i found it

```
 String query = "SELECT Cart_Date from Tbl_Cart where Cart_ID="+lastId+" ";
          Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
           if (c != null && c.moveToFirst() ) {
               s = c.getLong(0);

           SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
           java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
           String datetime = dateFormat.format(date);

         if(!(datetime.equals(s)))
{

}
```